# sequelize beforeCreate hook is not executing

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I wrote a BeforeCreate hook in my sequelize model. when i hit create user route then it saying user.user_id can't be null and even before create hook function not executing. I have followed documentation of sequelize.They have mentioned same as I use.I wrote a BeforeCreate hook in my sequelize model. when i hit create user route then it saying user.user_id can't be null and even before create hook function not executing. I have followed documentation of sequelize.They have mentioned same as I use.

```
const sequelize = require("kvell-db-plugin-sequelize").dbInstance;
const Sequelize = require("kvell-db-plugin-sequelize").dbLib;
const shortid = require("shortid");
const User = sequelize.define(
  "user",
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_id: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true
    },
    user_fname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_lname: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_fullName: {
      type: Sequelize.VIRTUAL,
      get() {
        return `${this.user_fname} ${this.user_lname}`;
      },
      set(value) {
        throw new Error("Do not try to set the `fullName` value!");
      }
    },
    user_email: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true
      },

      unique: {
        args: true,
        msg: "Email address already in use!"
      }
    },
    user_credential: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_roles: {
      type: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.STRING),
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: ["Admin"]
    },
    admin: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: true
    },
    user_img: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    }
  },
  {
    timestamps: true

 }
);

User.beforeCreate(async (user, options) => {
  console.log("inside hooks");
  let id = `user_${shortid.generate()}`;
  user.user_id = id;
});

const toJSON = User.prototype.toJSON;

User.prototype.toJSON = function({ attributes = [] } = {}) {
  const obj = toJSON.call(this);

  if (!attributes.length) {
    return obj;
  }

  return attributes.reduce((result, attribute) => {
    result[attribute] = obj[attribute];

    return result;
  }, {});
};

module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 user_id: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true
    }
```

In this section I have set user_id `allowNull = false` beforeCreate execute after the beforeValidate hook. But in beforeValidate hooks it was throwing error cause of `user.user_id===null` so i allowed `allowNull===true` and now it's working.

Comment: Could you show full code example of what you did. Im having the same issue.

Comment: I have same issues but now OK. We need to make sure that our model attributes do not encounter any validation error. Please see this: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/hooks.html#hooks-firing-order.

Answer (score 12):

The real answer (alluded to, but not explicitly stated, in one of the comments) is that `beforeCreate` hooks are applied *after* model validation.

This means if you have any field in your model (eg `id` ) which cannot be null, Sequelize will evaluate this prior to applying the `beforeCreate` field. In your case, Sequelize never gets as far as the `beforeCreate` hook, because the null `id` is failing validation every time.

Your accepted answer works around this by setting `allowNull = true`, thus circumventing the validation of your (briefly) null `id`. But the better option (rather than to distort your model by allowing null `id`) is almost certainly to instead use the correct hook:  `beforeValidate`. This hook is applied *before* the model criteria are evaluated.

It is a very simple change:

```
User.beforeValidate(async (user, options) => {
  console.log("inside hooks");
  let id = `user_${shortid.generate()}`;
  user.user_id = id;
});
```

NB: `async` is redundant here.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove **async** in this piece of your code:

```
async (user, options)
```